# "%option nodefault " causes "flex scanner jammed"

Tags: flex-lexer

I am using flex to read from a source file and then generate an output file. The lexer justs reads every character and write it into the output.
When I turned off "%option nodefault", everything works fine. However, when I turned it on, flex complains about "warning, -s option given but default rule can be matched", and when I run the binary, it crashed with "flex scanner jammed". Can anyone tell me the difference/problem?

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();

%}
%option noyywrap

%%

.               { fwrite(yytext, yyleng, 1, yyout); }
%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *sourceFile = fopen("swflow.dfd", "r");
    FILE *genFile;

    if(sourceFile) {
        genFile = fopen("swflow.v", "w+");
    }
    else {
        cout << "Cannot open source file!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    yyin = sourceFile;
    yyout = genFile;
    while(yylex());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`.` doesn't match a newline character. Your input probably includes a newline, and you have no rule which matches it. Since you've told flex to not generate a default rule, it has no way to handle the unmatched character so it complains.

To match any character, you need `.|\n`.

Comment: Now I understand and maybe next time I should first check my regular expression. Thanks!